# Desactivar acceso con shift en Access

Tags: base-de-datos, vba, ms-access

estoy implementando una BBDD en Access en la que se navega con formularios. El problema que tengo es que me interesa solo poder editar la BBDD yo, para lo que tendría que bloquear el acceso manteniendo SHIFT, ya que dejan de tener sentido las contraseñas que hay en el interior para limitar las acciones de los usuarios.

Es decir, estoy buscando cómo poner una contraseña o algo a la "puerta de atrás" por la que accedes manteniendo la tecla SHIFT. He encontrado como caparla para siempre, pero me interesa poder acceder yo a ella para añadir actualizaciones a la BBDD.

Un saludo y gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Creo que a tu pregunta le falta algo mas de desarrollo consulta [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo he solucionado, he creado otro formulario con contraseña para acceder en el que he colocado dos botones: habilitar_edicion y deshabilitar edicion. El código VBA para dichos botones es:

```
    Private Sub deshabilitar_edicion_Click()
    On Error GoTo err
    CurrentDb.Properties("allowbypasskey") = False
    Exit Sub
    err:
    CurrentDb.Properties.Append CurrentDb.CreateProperty("allowbypasskey", 1, False)
    End Sub

    Private Sub habilitar_edicion_Click()
    On Error GoTo err
    CurrentDb.Properties("allowbypasskey") = True
    Exit Sub
    err:
    CurrentDb.Properties.Append CurrentDb.CreateProperty("allowbypasskey", 1, True)
    End Sub
```

De esta forma, si quiero habilitar la "entrada trasera" tengo que abrir la BBDD, acceder al formulario introduciendo la contraseña y darle click al botón habilitar_edicion. A continuación cierro la BBDD y ya puedo entrar usando SHIFT. Para deshabilitar otra vez la entrada hay que hacer el mismo proceso pero dándole al otro botón o darle al botón directamente desde edición o correr el código de VBA.